# Burning CD/DVD using IMAPI2.dll

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am trying to add the facility to burn CD/DVD into my app by using IMAPI2.dll. I am using **Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9 SP 2 to devolopment**. When I invork the method Write() which is a member of the  IMAPI2.MsftDiscFormat2Data class (Last line of the sample code) Visual FoxPro gives the following error message. Error Msg : **"OLE error code 0x80004002: No such interface supported."**

**OS : Windows 7**

Please Help.

```
**--Creating MsftDiscMaster2 object to connect to optical drives.
loDiscMaster = CREATEOBJECT("IMAPI2.MsftDiscMaster2")

**--Creating MsftDiscRecorder2 object for the specified burning device.
loRecorder = CREATEOBJECT("IMAPI2.MsftDiscRecorder2")
lcUniqueId = loDiscMaster.ITEM(0)
loRecorder.InitializeDiscRecorder(lcUniqueId)

**--Create an image stream for the specified directory.
loFileSystem = CREATEOBJECT("IMAPI2FS.MsftFileSystemImage")
loRootDir = loFileSystem.Root

**--Create the new disc format and set the recorder.
loDataWriter = CREATEOBJECT("IMAPI2.MsftDiscFormat2Data")
loDataWriter.Recorder = loRecorder
loDataWriter.ClientName = "IMAPIv2 TEST"

loFileSystem.ChooseImageDefaults(loRecorder)

**--Add the directory and its contents to the file system.
loRootDir.AddTree("F:\VSS",.F.)

**--Create an image from the file system
loResultImage = loFileSystem.CreateResultImage()
loStream = loResultImage.ImageStream

**--Write stream to disc using the specified recorder.
loDataWriter.Write(loStream)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are out of luck there.  FoxPro interacts with COM objects at a fairly high level.  In fact, it works in much the same way that VBScript interacts with COM.  Normally, if your code works in VBScript, it will also work in FoxPro.

This is actually a common problem with some ActiveX/COM libraries.  While the objects implemented in imapi2.dll and imapi2fs.dll all use [IDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318520%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - the highest level and most interoperable form of COM interface - some of the method parameters, method returns, and properties of those objects are not IDispatch.

Specifically, the ImageStream property returns something called an [IStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which inherits from [IUnknown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of IDispatch.  Because of this, the ImageStream property returns something that FoxPro doesn't know how to deal with.  FoxPro knows that it is a COM interface, but it doesn't know how to find or call the methods on that object.